# focus on page instead of an element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I use [mediaelement](http://mediaelementjs.com/) player on my webpage.

As soon the video starts playing the focus is on mediaelement player and not on page. Hence I can not scroll. I have to click outside of the player to scroll.

Is there a way in jquery/html to shift the focus on page rather on element within the page???

This might be the code which is creating issues. Please  help me get past this code. I dont own this code. Its from some other library that I use.

```
buildkeyboard: function(player, controls, layers, media) {

  var t = this;

  // listen for key presses
  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (player.hasFocus && player.options.enableKeyboard) {
      // find a matching key
      for (var i=0, il=player.options.keyActions.length; i<il; i++) {
        var keyAction = player.options.keyActions[i];

        for (var j=0, jl=keyAction.keys.length; j<jl; j++) {
          if (e.keyCode == keyAction.keys[j]) {
            e.preventDefault();
            keyAction.action(player, media, e.keyCode);
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return true;
  });

  // check if someone clicked outside a player region, then kill its focus
  $(document).click(function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).closest('.mejs-container').length == 0) {
      player.hasFocus = false;
    }
  });
},
```

Can I override these listeners in my code???

Comment: Is it a Flash component?

Comment: If it is then what is the soln?

Comment: @alex: depends on your browser.  Looks like they try html 5 then fall back to flash or silverlight depending.  Incidentally, I tried playing the video on their site.  I clicked "play" then could immediately scroll. You might view source on their home page to see what they do.

Comment: Please fix your code tabbing!

Answer (score 1):

Try using `window.focus()` to set focus back to containing page.